# Java - HttpURLConnection - Content-Length isn't shown in request header

Tags: java, post, httprequest

I create a normal HttpURLConnection-object. I set for example 3 request headers.

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) someURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "some_agent");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "some_content-type");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "some_content-length");
```

I look at setted request headers.

```
System.out.println(conn.getRequestProperties());
```

The header "Content-Length" is never contained in the result.

```
{User-Agent=[some_agent], Content-Type=[some_content-type]}
```

I am getting also  `null` if I call `conn.getRequestProperty("Content-Length")`.

The code works fine but why does "Content-Length" disappear?

Comment: It would not make much sense to set the Content-Length considering it is controlled by whatever `URL` you are trying to access.

Comment: @JoshM In a POST (or PUT), you need to set the Content-Length of the request body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set the content length; it's done automatically. You can, however, use `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()`, when the content length is known in advance.

Comment: When it is done automatically, is there a way to see the full request header that was sent?

Comment: Submit the request to a servlet that prints the headers: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-request-headers.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up `System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");`

More details about it(similar issue):
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1999694?tstart=0